# Creating directory using mkdir

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have assigned data command value to `new` and then I want to create a directory with the value assigned to `new` - `Date > new`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

date | awk '{print $5}' > new
mkdir $new
cat new 
ls
```

This is the script I have tried  but I hadn't found any output. Can anyone help me here to create a directory

Comment: Please reformat your question so that it faithfully depicts the script you launched. (taking care of case and newlines or poncuation.)

Comment: I have assigned data command value to new and
 then i want to create a directory with the value assigned to new
...........
Date > new ,,,,,
Mkdir $new

Comment: Please do comply with my first request. Because if what you launched was typed as you reported, the fact that it just does not do what you want is nothing but absolutely normal.

Comment: What about starting with lowercasing all the uppercases ?

Comment: Then understand that your first command did not assign any value to the *new* variable you are using in mkdir.

Comment: Output from date command is assigned to new
And I don't have any problem with upper case and lower case, anything is ok

Comment: @SivaE5209, your command **DO NOT ASSIGN** anything to `new` variable: `date | awk '{print $5}' > new`

Comment: With your command `date | awk '{print $5}'` what value from the date string do you want to capture?

Comment: Following on from roaima, The `print $5` here is equal to the 3 digit timezone, ie `GMT`.

Comment: Yes i want to create a directory with that time  at moment which captured

Answer (score 1):

The command you use:

```
date | awk '{print $5}' > new
```

create file (redirection via `>`) with name `new`. To assign to variable it should be:

```
new=$(date | awk '{print $5}')
```

When you create directory it is always wise to use `-p` to not report error when directory exist:

```
mkdir -p $new
```

`cat` command make sense if you have file, will not work (well) with directory. Also with first command you create file, then you use variable with the same name. This is not the way thighs work in `bash`.

Comment: I have tried both the cases
Still i don't have output

Comment: @SivaE5209, update your question with what you try and kind of error you get